# Force YTPlayerView quit fullscreen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I'm using [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) to play Youtube video in my app.

I want to quit fullscreen mode programmatically.

Here is my code to play video:

```
self.youtubePlayer.load(withVideoId: videoId, playerVars: ["controls" : 1,"playsinline" : 1,"autoplay": 1,"modestbranding" : 1,"fs" : 1,"rel" : 0])
```

Does it have anyway to force YTPlayerView to quit fullscreen mode when video is playing?

Comment: By having a quick look at https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/blob/master/Classes/YTPlayerView.h, seems like there is no function provided by that library.

Comment: @SahilManchanda Does you have any solution maybe not using official library?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any solution now. You may look for another library which might support what you need.